# How to change font size in gnome-shell panel

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, fonts

I tried gnome-shell in Ubuntu by using the `gnome-shell --replace` command. It works well but I think the font size in the shell panel is too big.

Is possible to custom the font size in gnome-shell panel?

Comment: you're going to have better luck on superuser.com

Answer (score 11):

Please change the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` accordingly. For example, if you want to change panel font, you can add `font-family: "FontName"` into `.panel-button`. And you can further customize the font of the Dashboard, etc.

You can checkout my blog post on customizing gnome-shell: http://joneslee85.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/howto-customize-gnome-shell-theme/

Answer (score 4):

Found this:

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme
sudo gedit gnome-shell.css
```

I've played around with some of the settings in the gnome-shell.css file and through a bit of trial and error, managed to increase the size of the text underneath the Application icons. On line 638, I increased font-size from 7.5pt to 11.5pt which made it more readable.
Code:

```
.app-well-app > .overview-icon,
.remove-favorite > .overview-icon,
.search-result-content > .overview-icon {
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    font-size: 7.5pt;
    color: white;
    transition-duration: 100;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I also decided to decrease the size of the icons.

```
.icon-grid .overview-icon {
    icon-size: 96px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. I had the same problem :)

1. You have to edit file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js`.
2. Find a line `const DEFAULT_FONT` and change font size (or even name).
3. After this you have to restart gnome-shell: press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>r</kbd>, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

BTW: You can customize almost everything by editing JavaScript files located in the `ui` directory.

Answer (score 2):

The posts recommending editing `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` are correct; however, it should be noted that if you are using an alternate gnome-shell theme (e.g. you are running Linux Mint), there may be additional editable files.

For example, Mint12's 'Mint-Z' theme has configurable .css files in `/usr/share/themes/Mint-Z`.

Additionally, gnome-shell extensions may have their own configurable .css files, located in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/{extension id}/` or `$HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/{extension id}/`.  I am not sure though if these settings can override theme defaults.

EDIT: 
@Guilherme actually answers your question.

FYI On my system (`gnome-shell 3.2.1-0ubuntu1`), the appropriate css selector is located in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css`, at line 720, and is set to `7.5pt`.  The actual setting for my Mint12 system, however, is in `/usr/share/themes/Mint-Z/gnome-shell.css`, @line 880, and is set to `8pt`.  Modify this value, then reload your theme using the 'rt' command at the `ALT+F2` prompt.

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/vte/termcap/xterm
```

Edit this line:

```
:co#80:it#8:li#24:\
```

Source:

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=15471

Comment: The question is about the graphical "GNOME Shell", not the terminal emulator. (Also, do *not* edit system-wide terminfo, it will be overriden by updates. Use `infocmp xterm > xterm.ti` and `tic xterm.ti`.)